# Multiple pie charts using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to display two charts at the same time using matplotlib.

But I have to close one graph then only I can see the other graph.
Is there anyway to display both the graphs or more number of graphs at the same time.

Here is my code

```
num_pass=np.size(data[0::,1].astype(np.float))
num_survive=np.sum(data[0::,1].astype(np.float))
prop=num_survive/num_pass
num_dead=num_pass-num_survive
#print num_dead


labels='Dead','Survived'
sizes=[num_dead,num_survive]
colors=['darkorange','green']
mp.axis('equal')
mp.title('Titanic Survival Chart')
mp.pie(sizes, explode=(0.02,0), labels=labels,colors=colors,autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
mp.show()

women_only_stats = data[0::,4] == "female" 
men_only_stats = data[0::,4] != "female" 

# Using the index from above we select the females and males separately
women_onboard = data[women_only_stats,1].astype(np.float)     
men_onboard = data[men_only_stats,1].astype(np.float)

labels='Men','Women'
sizes=[np.sum(women_onboard),np.sum(men_onboard)]
colors=['purple','red']
mp.axis('equal')
mp.title('People on board')
mp.pie(sizes, explode=(0.01,0), labels=labels,colors=colors,autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
mp.show()
```

How can I show both the graphs at the same time?

Comment: You should call `mp.show()` only at the end after creating all the plots.

Comment: @Banana did that too, it shows the second pie chart completely overlapping the first one. I can see the values of the first pie but not the actual chart.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, and the simplest is to use multiple figure numbers. Simply tell `matplotlib` that you are working on separate figures, and then show them simultaneously:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(0)
# Create first chart here.

plt.figure(1)
# Create second chart here.

plt.show() #show all figures
```

Comment: It shows all figures separately

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Banana's answer, you could also plot them in different subplots within the same figure:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data1 = np.array([0.9, 0.1])
data2 = np.array([0.6, 0.4])

# create a figure with two subplots
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

# plot each pie chart in a separate subplot
ax1.pie(data1)
ax2.pie(data2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: These look like oval charts, rather than circular... How to adjust their visualization?

Comment: @FC84 You can set the aspect ratio of the subplots to be equal, e.g. `plt.subplots(1, 2, subplot_kw={'aspect':'equal'})`

Comment: @ali_m, complication of OP: how to plot multiple pie charts centered at specified (x,y) coordinates in a single plot and with varying size?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can put multiple pies on the same figure using subplots/multiple axes:

```
mp.subplot(211)
mp.pie(..)
mp.subplot(212)
mp.pie(...)
mp.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This answer of `User:Banana` worked for me.

I had 4 graphs and all 4 popped up as individual pie charts when I ran the `plt.show()` so I believe you can use as many **figure** numbers as you want.

```
plt.figure(0)   # Create first chart here and specify all parameters below.
plt.figure(1)   # Create second chart here and specify all parameters below.
plt.figure(3)   # Create third chart here and specify all parameters below.
plt.figure(4)   # Create fourth chart here and specify all parameters below.
plt.show()      # show all figures.
```